# Add custom fields to custom product calculated price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-fields

In Woocommerce, I added some custom fields to my product single pages, based on this answer code: [Add a custom product calculated price to Woocommerce cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50450056/add-a-custom-product-calculated-price-to-woocommerce-cart).

This is my code:

```
// Add a custom field before single add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_price_field', 5 );
function custom_product_price_field(){
echo '<div class="custom-text text">
<h3>Rental</h3>
<label>Start Date:</label>    
<input type="date" name="rental_date" value="" class="rental_date" />
<label>Period Rental:</label>
<select name="custom_price" class="custom_price">
            <option value="70" selected="selected">2 days</option>
            <option value="40">4 days</option>                
        </select>
</div>';
}

// Get custom field value, calculate new item price, save it as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_field_data', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_field_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
if (! isset($_POST['custom_price']))
    return $cart_item_data;

$custom_price = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_price'] );
if( empty($custom_price) )
    return $cart_item_data;

$product    = wc_get_product($product_id); // The WC_Product Object
$base_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Product reg price

// New price calculation
$new_price = $base_price * $custom_price/100;

// Set the custom amount in cart object
$cart_item_data['custom_data']['rental'] = (float) $custom_price;
$cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price'] = (float) $new_price;   
$cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); 
// Make each item unique

return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set the new calculated cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'extra_price_add_custom_price', 20, 1 );
function extra_price_add_custom_price( $cart ) {
if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') )
    return;

foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['new_price']) )
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) $cart_item['custom_data']['new_price'] );
}
}

// Display cart item custom price details
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_items_custom_price_details', 20, 3 );
function display_cart_items_custom_price_details( $product_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['rental']) ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    $product_price  = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_regular_price() ) ) );
    $product_price .= '<br>' . wc_price( $cart_item['custom_data']['rental'] ).'&nbsp;';
    $product_price .= __("rental", "woocommerce" );     
}
return $product_price;
}
```

I need to show the date in the cart, that the user has selected in the calendar.

```
<input type="date" name="rental_date" value="" class="rental_date" />
```

When selected a rental period, everything works and appears in the shopping cart. But I need to make percentages:

```
<select name="custom_price" class="custom_price">
    <option value="30%" selected="selected">2 days</option>
    <option value="60%">4 days</option>                
</select>
```

If the user selects "2 days", 30% of the base price is calculated. If "4 days" is calculated 60%.

For example, the product costs $200. The user selects "2 days" equal to 30% and receives a product cost of $140. Similarly, if you select "4 days".

How can I do that?

I will be glad to your help!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I added `$new_price = $base_price/100 * $custom_price;` and `<option value="30" selected="selected">2 days</option> <option value="60">4 days</option>` It works, but is this the right decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 4** - Try the following (hopping is that you want):

```
// Add a custom field before single add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_price_field', 5 );
function custom_product_price_field(){
    echo '<div class="custom-text text">
    <h3>Rental</h3>
    <label>Start Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="rental_date" value="" class="rental_date" />
    <label>Period Rental:</label>
    <select name="custom_price" class="custom_price">
        <option value="70" selected="selected">2 days</option>
        <option value="40">4 days</option> 
    </select>
    </div>';
}

// Get custom field value, calculate new item price, save it as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_field_data', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_field_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
    if ( isset($_POST['rental_date']) && ! empty($_POST['rental_date']) ){
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['date'] = $_POST['rental_date'];
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['custom_price']) && ! empty($_POST['custom_price']) ){
        $product      = wc_get_product($product_id); // The WC_Product Object
        $base_price   = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Product reg price
        $custom_price = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_price'] );

        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['base_price'] = $base_price;
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price'] = $base_price/100 * $custom_price;
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['rental'] = $custom_price;
    }
    if ( isset($cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price']) || isset($cart_item_data['custom_data']['date']) ){
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); // Make each item unique
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set the new calculated cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'extra_price_add_custom_price', 20, 1 );
function extra_price_add_custom_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['new_price']) )
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) $cart_item['custom_data']['new_price'] );
    }
}

// Display cart item custom price details
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_items_custom_price_details', 20, 3 );
function display_cart_items_custom_price_details( $product_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['base_price']) ) {
        $product        = $cart_item['data'];
        $base_price     = $cart_item['custom_data']['base_price'];
        $product_price  = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $base_price ) ) ) . '<br>';
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['rental']) ) {
            $product_price .= $cart_item['custom_data']['rental'] == '70' ? __("2 days") : __("4 days");
        }
    }
    return $product_price;
}

// Display in cart item the selected date
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_data']['date'] ) ){

        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __("Chosen date", "woocommerce" ),
            'value' =>   date('d.m.Y', strtotime($cart_item['custom_data']['date'])),
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Can we then instead of "% of the base price rental" show the number of days that the user choose? I mean, to show "2 days" or "4 days" Thanks!

Comment: not really (((... If you set the same percentage value to 30%, `<option value="30%" selected="selected">2 days</option>  <option value="30%">4 days</option>` then only "2 days" is displayed, and "4 days" is not displayed.

Comment: @Dmitry You can't set the same values in the options of a select field, as you can not get which option has been selected. A select field always send a the selected option **value**, never the option displayed label name…

Comment: And how to turn the date over? Need to show 08.31.2018

Comment: @Dmitry that is easy… See I have updated the code and the date is displayed in cart like "08.31.2018" …

Comment: Thank you so much!