# Set a calculated price for variable products in the WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-fields

In Woocommerce, I use custom fields to calculate the price of a product, based on this code - [Add custom fields to custom product calculated price in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51996543/add-custom-fields-to-custom-product-calculated-price-in-woocommerce). Thanks for the help LoicTheAztec.

```
// Add a custom field before single add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_price_field', 5 );
function custom_product_price_field(){
echo '<div class="custom-text text">
<h3>Rental</h3>
<label>Start Date:</label>
<input type="date" name="rental_date" value="" class="rental_date" />
<label>Period Rental:</label>
<select name="custom_price" class="custom_price">
    <option value="30" selected="selected">2 days</option>
    <option value="35">4 days</option> 
</select>
</div>';
}

// Get custom field value, calculate new item price, save it as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_field_data', 20, 2 );
function add_custom_field_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ){
if ( isset($_POST['rental_date']) && ! empty($_POST['rental_date']) ){
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['date'] = $_POST['rental_date'];
}
if ( isset($_POST['custom_price']) && ! empty($_POST['custom_price']) ){
    $product      = wc_get_product($product_id); // The WC_Product Object
    $base_price   = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Product reg price
    $custom_price = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_price'] );

    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['base_price'] = $base_price;
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price'] = $base_price * $custom_price/100;
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['rental'] = $custom_price;
}
if ( isset($cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price']) || isset($cart_item_data['custom_data']['date']) ){
    $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); // Make each item unique
}
return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set the new calculated cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'extra_price_add_custom_price', 20, 1 );
function extra_price_add_custom_price( $cart ) {
if ( is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX') )
    return;

foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['new_price']) )
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) $cart_item['custom_data']['new_price'] );
}
}

// Display cart item custom price details
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_items_custom_price_details', 20, 3 );
function display_cart_items_custom_price_details( $product_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['new_price']) ) {
    $product        = $cart_item['data'];
    $new_price     = $cart_item['custom_data']['new_price'];
    $product_price  = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $new_price ) ) ) . '<br>';
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['rental']) ) {
        $product_price .= $cart_item['custom_data']['rental'] == '30' ? __("2 days") : __("4 days");
    }
}
return $product_price;
}

// Display in cart item the selected date
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_data']['date'] ) ){

    $cart_item_data[] = array(
        'name' => __("Chosen date", "woocommerce" ),
        'value' =>   date('d.m.Y', strtotime($cart_item['custom_data']['date'])),
    );
}
if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_data']['rental'] ) ){
    $cart_item_data[] = array(
        'name' => __("Period Rental", "woocommerce" ),
        'value' =>   $cart_item['custom_data']['rental'] == '30' ? __("2 days") : __("4 days"),         
    );
}
return $cart_item_data;
}
```

I decided to create a new question, because I think it is appropriate in this case.

All the code is completely working, but there is a problem. This code works for simple products, and I have a lot of variational products.

[image]

This code does not show the price of variational products. It shows only the date and the period.

[image]

How to solve this problem? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

In your code, you need to change `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data()` function, to handle product variations.

There is other some other arguments that can be used as `$variation_id` in this hook.

The code:

```
// Add a custom field before single add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_product_price_field', 5 );
function custom_product_price_field(){
    echo '<div class="custom-text text">
    <h3>Rental</h3>
    <label>Start Date:</label>
    <input type="date" name="rental_date" value="" class="rental_date" />
    <label>Period Rental:</label>
    <select name="custom_price" class="custom_price">
        <option value="30" selected="selected">2 days</option>
        <option value="35">4 days</option>
    </select>
    </div>';
}

// Get custom field value, calculate new item price, save it as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_field_data', 20, 3 );
function add_custom_field_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){
    if ( isset($_POST['rental_date']) && ! empty($_POST['rental_date']) ){
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['date'] = $_POST['rental_date'];
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['custom_price']) && ! empty($_POST['custom_price']) ){
        $_product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
        $product      = wc_get_product($_product_id); // The WC_Product Object
        $base_price   = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Product reg price
        $custom_price = (float) sanitize_text_field( $_POST['custom_price'] );

        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['base_price'] = $base_price;
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price'] = $base_price/100 * $custom_price;
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['rental'] = $custom_price;
    }
    if ( isset($cart_item_data['custom_data']['new_price']) || isset($cart_item_data['custom_data']['date']) ){
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime() . rand() ); // Make each item unique
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Set the new calculated cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'extra_price_add_custom_price', 20, 1 );
function extra_price_add_custom_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['new_price']) )
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) $cart_item['custom_data']['new_price'] );
    }
}

// Display cart item custom price details
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'display_cart_items_custom_price_details', 20, 3 );
function display_cart_items_custom_price_details( $product_price, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['base_price']) ) {
        $product        = $cart_item['data'];
        $base_price     = $cart_item['custom_data']['base_price'];
        $product_price  = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $base_price ) ) ) . '<br>';
        if( isset($cart_item['custom_data']['rental']) ) {
            $product_price .= $cart_item['custom_data']['rental'] == '30' ? __("2 days") : __("4 days");
        }
    }
    return $product_price;
}

// Display in cart item the selected date
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_item_data', 10, 2 );
function display_custom_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_data']['date'] ) ){

        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __("Chosen date", "woocommerce" ),
            'value' =>   date('d.m.Y', strtotime($cart_item['custom_data']['date'])),
        );
    }
    if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_data']['rental'] ) ){
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __("Period Rental", "woocommerce" ),
            'value' =>   $cart_item['custom_data']['rental'] == '30' ? __("2 days") : __("4 days"),
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]